# GET http://localhost:8080/system/users/modify/:id 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

I am getting following error on click of modify button

```
GET http://localhost:8080/system/users/modify/:id 400 (Bad Request)
```

js code

```
 .when('/users/modify/:id', {
            templateUrl: '/system/users/modify/:id',
            controller: 'ModifyUserController'            
        })
```

here is java code

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/users/modify/{id}")
public String modifyUser(@PathVariable int id, @ModelAttribute(value = "loginModel") LoginModel loginModel, Model model) {   
    return "system/users/modifyUser";
}
```

it works if make the java header like this

```
public String modifyUser(@ModelAttribute(value = "loginModel") LoginModel loginModel, Model model) {
```

but I want to get the id in this method

Comment: What happens when you use `public String modifyUser(@PathVariable("id") int id)` ???

Comment: can you show the Angular template which contains the button?

Comment: @geoand same error, see the updated question

Comment: In the browser console, can you see that is being sent over HTTP and post it? Thanks!

Comment: Request URL:http://localhost:8080/system/users/modify/:id
Request Method:GET
Status Code:400 
Bad Request The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately its not auto binding the param variable and I have to apply it my self like this

```
templateUrl: function(param) {
    return '/system/users/modify/' + param.id;
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the call that is being picked up by the Web server is actually 
`GET http://localhost:8080/system/users/modify/:id`(the :id is not being replaced by Angular, or you are just calling it like that for testing purposes)

the problem is that you are specifying that `id` must be an `int`. But in this case where you are not sending an `int`, so Spring complains and a HTTP 400 is being thrown

Comment: yes u r right, in network tab its trying to request for url /modify/:id  how to replace that id with actual id?

Comment: I am not familiar with Angular, so I can't really help you with that :(